# how to write a sparql for retrieving the birth place of a famous person?

Tags: sparql

i want to write a sparql when the users introduce the name of a famous person and the application displays the country where s/he was born. For example, if the user introduces “Siddiq Barmak” the application would display “Afghanistan”.

Comment: If a user enters “Siddiq Barmak” you have to find the URI of the corresponding resource, right? And then you can add a triple pattern to the query: `SELECT ?birthPlace { <RESOURCE_URI> <BIRTH_PLACE_PROPERTY_URI> ?birthPlace }`

Comment: can you please provide an example? it will be very helpful

Comment: What? I already gave you the answer. It's your turn to figure out the corresponding URI. I'm wondering whether you know that in RDF the resources are identified by URIs and not by "words"?

Comment: i could not figure out the corresponding URI if you can help it will be appreciated

Comment: **how** can I know the URI of the resource given that I don't know which RDF dataset you're using?!

Comment: I am using DbPedia

Comment: And what is so difficult then? DBpedia is based on Wikipedia, thus, use the Wikipedia entry `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siddiq_Barmak` which maps to the DBpedia entry `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Siddiq_Barmak`. Even if you don't know this, using a search engine like Google with "DBpedia + Siddiq Barmak" should show up the same among the first results.